# Issue with downloading zip file from internet

Tags: python

Issue with downloading zip file from internet

```
import requests
url = '"file:///Users/rituraj/Downloads/fo01NOV2018bhav.csv%20(1).zip"'

# download the file contents in binary format
r = requests.get(url)

with open("/Users/rituraj/Desktop/bhavcopy/myzip.zip","wb") as zip:
    zip.write(r.content)
```

Error I get:

```
    AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-17-8b95bb6c7ef7> in <module> 
   3 import zipfile 4 ----> 5  urllib.urlretrieve('file:///Users/rituraj/Downloads/fo01NOV2018bhav.csv%20.zip') 6 7 
    # download the file contents in binary format AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Just wondering why you double-quoted the URL!

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-8b95bb6c7ef7> in <module>
      3 import zipfile
      4 
----> 5 urllib.urlretrieve('file:///Users/rituraj/Downloads/fo01NOV2018bhav.csv%20.zip')
      6 
      7 # download the file contents in binary format

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Comment: Why are you using requests for a local file?